# Kinect Body Tracking GetAndRefreshBodyData returns error

Tags: c++, kinect

Trying to get a body tracked by Kinect V2 using C++ but its not working as its supposed to, Also the Microsoft's documentation on C++ API for kinect V2 is exceptionally poor

relevant code snippet:

```
HRESULT result;

if (BodyFrameReader != nullptr)
{
    result = BodyFrameReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&BodyFrame);
    if (result == S_OK)
    {
        IBody** bodies =nullptr;

            result = BodyFrame->GetAndRefreshBodyData(BODY_COUNT, bodies);


        if (result == S_OK)
            Print("Success");
        else
            Print("Fail "+result );

        BodyFrame->Release();
    }
}
```

So the first result on reading the frame using `AcquireLatestFrame` returns `S_OK` however trying to get info for any tracked body using `GetAndRefreshBodyData` always returns an error code in the variable `result` which is some very large negative number (-ve MAXINT_32) .

Apart from this another thing I've noticed is in some docs it hints as if `GetAndRefreshBodyData` needs an array of `IBody` as a parameter now `IBody` is an interface and it can't be instantiated so how are you supposed to do that.

Is there some additional setup needs to be done apart from `Kinect->Open()` to get to body tracking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, Microsoft's documentation is pretty bad. But the SDK comes with quite a few sample projects, which are always a good starting point. For your case, take a look at the BodyBasics C++ sample. There you'll find code like the following:

```
IBody* ppBodies[BODY_COUNT] = {0}; // BODY_COUNT is 6
hr = pBodyFrame->GetAndRefreshBodyData(_countof(ppBodies), ppBodies);
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks. Most Samples and online docs focus on C# so I kind of overlooked this one

Comment: When you installed the Kinect SDK, it also installed the "SDK Browser". Using that, you can filter the samples, so it only shows you the C++ ones.

Comment: Don't forget to release to avoid memory leak.
for(int i=0; i<BODY_COUNT; i++){ if(ppBodies[i]!=nullptr) ppBodies[i]->Release();}